# Recurring events in Google's Datastore / NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, calendar, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an `Event` model with `start_time` & `end_time` of `ndb.DateTimeProperty()` property types.

I normally query for events with a query like `Event.query(Event.start_time >= START_OF_THE_MONTH, Event.start_time <= END_OF_THE_MONTH)`.

What would be the best approach to add support of recurring events?

First thing that comes to mind is to create each of the events individually but with an event repeating daily - that's a lot of created entities (and to what point would they need to be created? for a year? for 10 years?). While this approach would make the existing code & queries work - it's very expensive and inefficient.

Next, creating only one entity for the entire recurring event with a property that stores a rule of how often the event repeats, and then, in addition to the query above - querying the model again for all recurring events might work but only until some point when there are too many recurring events...

What else is there that's suitable for `ndb` and is scalable, ideally with the least amount of changes to existing code / queries?

Comment: How many events do you expect to manage every month?

Comment: @janscas I don't expect many at all, shouldn't be more than ~15-20 per user, I'm just worried about worst case scenarios where a user might create several daily recurring events (testing things or whatever, which will slow down the app a bit for that user if an entity per event is created and a monthly view is requested).

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you need to query for events in a given month of the year. I also suppose the recurring events have some sort of expiration date.

So, what you can do is change the start_date property to be a repeated property (if this breakes some of your code you can create a new property called 'target_dates' or whatever).

```
target_dates = ndb.DateProperty(repeated=True, indexed=True)
```

Then when you store the event, compute the range of dates (in months) this event is available and store them as a list:

```
start_date = datetime.date(year=2017, month=1, day=1)
end_date = datetime.date(year=2017, month=5, day=1)
target_dates = [datetime.date(year=2017, month=1, day=1), ... , datetime.date(year=2017, month=5, day=1)]
```

What I would do then, is to do the same query as you did but with the target_dates.

Another approach is to do two separate keys only queries (fast and cheap queries since they use the property index). One query to query the non recurring events in the month and another one to query the recurring events (using the end date maybe). Then join the result set and get the entities with get_multi. Plus you gain cached entities here.

I'm not sure is this will fit into your app but with the information provided is all I can help you right now.